# Unexpected Seq Scan when doing query against boolean with value NULL

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-8.3

I have a database column called `auto_review` where column type is `boolean`.
There is an index for that field, created using the ActiveRecord ORM.

```
CREATE INDEX index_table_on_auto_renew ON table USING btree (auto_renew);
```

When I query the field for a boolean value, PG uses the index as expected.

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "table".* FROM "table"  WHERE "table"."auto_renew" = 'f'
                                          QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on table  (cost=51.65..826.50 rows=28039 width=186)
   Filter: (NOT auto_renew)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_domains_on_auto_renew  (cost=0.00..44.64 rows=2185 width=0)
         Index Cond: (auto_renew = false)
(4 rows)
```

When the value is `NULL`, a sequential scan is used.

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "table".* FROM "table"  WHERE "table"."auto_renew" IS NULL
                           QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..1094.01 rows=25854 width=186)
   Filter: (auto_renew IS NULL)
(2 rows)
```

I'm curious to know the reason behind this choice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally, `col IS NULL` is a possible candidate for a (default) b-tree index search. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-types.html):

> Also, an `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` condition on an index column can be
>   used with a B-tree index.

To get proof, disable sequential scans (in a test session only!):

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE):

> `enable_seqscan (boolean)`
>
> Enables or disables the query planner's use of sequential scan plan types.
>   It is impossible to suppress sequential scans entirely,
>   but turning this variable off discourages the planner from using one
>   if there are other methods available. The default is on.

Then try again:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE auto_renew IS NULL;
```

This will probably result in a bitmap index scan that is **slower** than a sequential scan on the table.

Reset, or close the session (the setting is session-local).

```
RESET enable_seqscan;
```

Indexes on `boolean` columns are only useful in certain cases. The planner only uses an index if it expects that to be faster. Calculations are based on your [cost settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) and the statistics gathered by `ANALYZE`. If a sizable portion of the table matches your condition (around 5% or more, it depends), it is typically faster to do a full table scan instead.

This leaves the *rare* value in a `boolean` column as the only useful candidate for a plain index. And it is typically more efficient to create a (more specialized) [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) instead for this - which is cheaper to maintain, smaller, faster and used more readily if query condition match.

If you have lots of queries looking for rows with `auto_renew IS NULL` and the `NULL` case is not very common (and / or you need a certain sort order) then this index would help to find / sort these rows quickly:

```
CREATE INDEX index_tbl_tbl_id_auto_renew_null ON tbl (tbl_id)
WHERE auto_renew IS NULL;
```

The condition of the partial index has to be repeated in the `WHERE` clause of a query more or less exactly to make the query planner realize the index is applicable.

The indexed column (`tbl_id`) is an arbitrary pick. The important part is the `WHERE` clause. This particular index would be most effective for queries with `ORDER BY tbl_id` or an additional filter or join on `tbl_id`. You could make it a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html). Boolean columns are often more useful in combination with others.

Aside: ORMs are crutches that regularly fail to get the full potential out of your RDBMS.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you Erwin. I'm sad I can't upvote it twice.