# Temp files and work_mem

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, memory, configuration

My Postgres instance is logging things like this:

```
2021-11-16 22:18:52.491 UTC [1808765]: [3-1] db=xxx,user=xxx LOG: temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp1808765.0", size 262144
```

My understanding is that if `work_mem` is too low, Postgres can use a temporary file for sorting. But if I run `show work_mem;` I see that the current value is 86000kB, which is much bigger than the size of the temp files I see mentioned in the logs. Is there something else I should be looking at here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to understand what the `work_mem` setting actually does. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM)

> `work_mem` (`integer`)
>
> Sets the base maximum amount of memory to be used by a query operation (such as a sort or hash table) before writing to temporary
> disk files. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as
> kilobytes. The default value is four megabytes (`4MB`). Note that for a
> complex query, several sort or hash operations might be running in
> parallel; each operation will generally be allowed to use as much
> memory as this value specifies before it starts to write data into
> temporary files. Also, several running sessions could be doing such
> operations concurrently. Therefore, the total memory used could be
> many times the value of `work_mem`; it is necessary to keep this fact
> in mind when choosing the value. Sort operations are used for `ORDER BY`, `DISTINCT`, and merge joins. Hash tables are used in hash joins,
> hash-based aggregation, result cache nodes and hash-based processing
> of IN subqueries.
>
> Hash-based operations are generally more sensitive to memory availability than equivalent sort-based operations. The memory
> available for hash tables is computed by multiplying `work_mem` by
> `hash_mem_multiplier`. This makes it possible for hash-based
> operations to use an amount of memory that exceeds the usual
> `work_mem` base amount.

([`hash_mem_multiplier` was added in Postgres 13.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html#id-1.11.6.10.5.3.5))

If Postgres needs more memory than `work_mem` allows for any given operation, it starts spilling to disk. So what you observed is the ***excess***:

> I see that the current value is 86000kB, which is much bigger than the size of the temp files I see mentioned in the logs.

Increase your `work_mem` setting (at least) by the size of the observed temporary file and it should go away.

However, don't set `work_mem` too high, either, as that might starve out cache and concurrent transactions. One can always set a higher `work_mem` locally for exceptionally big operations. See:

- [Slow query performance due to temporary file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112079/slow-query-performance-due-to-temporary-file/112185#112185)
- [Increasing work_mem and shared_buffers on Postgres 9.2 significantly slows down queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/increasing-work-mem-and-shared-buffers-on-postgres-9-2-significantly-slows-down/33622)

Comment: > So what you observed is the excess:

Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.